# How to make all documents inside Document Set use same properties as Document Set

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, document-set

I have a document library with following columns apart from the default ones.

Reference Number
Customer Name

I created a new document set inside this library and set values of above fields. Then I uploaded a new document inside the document set and I am able to set the above fields again for the newly uploaded document.

What I want is when a document is uploaded, user shouldn't be able to set values for above fields because they have already been set for that document set.

Got my point? So basically all documents inside a document set shall have same properties (apart from default ones which of course will be different such as Created, Created By etc.)

How to do this?

Comment: You could hide the fields by setting ShowInNewForm and ShowInEditForm to false?

Comment: And how do I do that? Do I need to write some Event Receiver or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new custom Content Type with base as Document Set. Add the two Site columns **Reference Number** and **Customer Name** to that particular content type. In custom Document Set content Type , go to **Document Set Settings** and make the 2 columns as shared. Now all the documents inside the document set will share the value for that 2 columns. also go to the Library where you are using this Document Sets and inside the Document Content Type make the **2 columns Hidden** from all forms. So now these 2 columns will be visible only when you create new document sets but not while adding documents.

Comment: I was about to post the answer as I have already found the solution you posted about Sharing columns. But I don't think hidden part will work because then any documents uploaded in root (not in document set) will also have their columns hidden. I only want to hide for documents inside Document Set.

Comment: then you will have to create custom content type with base as document, hide the columns and make it available inside the document set. Upload documents with the custom document content type inside the document set and outside document set using normal document CT

Comment: Thanks for the solution. One thing is not clear as to how can I make the new content type available in Document Set?

Comment: Ok I got the solution. It's inside Document Set settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a specific content type for the documents that are added inside the document set, you can hide the columns so users cannot update the values.  The values will then be shared down from the document set instead.

In your content type, select the Reference Number/Customer Name and set the Column Settings to "Hidden".

Comment: In my library there is the default Document content type and then there is Document Set content type. The documents in Document Set use Document content type so if I hide it for this type, it will also hide for all documents that are uploaded on root.